# Setting up telegraf config file to enable data ingress

Tags: grafana, influxdb, flux, influxql

I want to use grafana to monitor data, utilizing the mathematical abilities of the FLUX query language.
For this purpose, I've set up an influxdb and a grafana server, and I installed telegraf.

```
user@Logger-0271:~$ influx
Connected to http://localhost:8086 version 1.8.2
InfluxDB shell version: 1.8.2
> show databases
name: databases
name
----
_internal
localdb
brunosdb
telegraf
> use brunosdb
Using database brunosdb
> show measurements
name: measurements
name
----
flowrate
ruecklauftemp
vorlauftemp
```

Within grafana, choosing InfluxDB as Query language (see below) I can plot the measurements just fine. However, if I choose FLUX, I'm only able to plot the measurements in the telegraf database.

```
> use telegraf
Using database telegraf
> show measurements
name: measurements
name
----
cpu
disk
diskio
kernel
mem
processes
swap
system
```

InfluxDB as Query Language:

[image]

FLUX as Query Language:

[image]

[image]

I tried to manually insert data into the telegraf database of the InfluxDB, but it does not appear as a grafana measurement.

How can I input data into the InfluxDB and then use FLUX in grafana to perform calculations and plot the data? I've read that the inputs have to be defined in the config file, I don't know how though ...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to enable an MQTT data ingress by changing the `[[inputs.mqtt_consumer]]` section of the config file.